# Sylius Best Practice for changing translation texts

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

What is the "best practice" for changing text in sylius?  More details below.

I'm a beginner to symfony2 and sylius.  I've been searching for documentation on this, so if it exist, please direct me to it!  I wouldn't be surprised if I missed it because I don't know hardly any of the terminology for working in symfony2.

My original goal that prompted me to ask this question was to change the title on my frontend hompage of a sylius install.  First I found Controller/Frontend/HomePageController.php, in that file I found this: SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Homepage:main.html.twig, which lead me to Resources/views/Homepage/main.html.twig Here I found {{ 'sylius.homepage.splash.headline'|trans }} which I noticed I could staticly change, but I want to "code better", so I looked for how I could edit that value, and after some digging a buddy of mine pointed me to Resources/translations/messages.en.xlf where I found

```
      <trans-unit id="ce71111cec2ffc480f4a947e170afa33" resname="sylius.homepage.splash.headline">
    <source>sylius.homepage.splash.headline</source>
    <target>Welcome to Sylius</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

Changing "Welcome to Sylius" here has the desired effect.  Is this where I should be changing the content of sylius.homepage.splash.headline? or is it the case that Resources/translations/messages.en.xlf will be overwritten with updates or something and I should do modifications somewhere else? If it's somewhere else, how / where do I do this?

Comment: Did you clear cache after you changed xlf file?

Comment: yep, it worked in the dev environment right away, but not in prod environment, which makes sense, as I understand that production uses cache, but dev does not.  My question is however, if this is the best practice way of changing text?

Comment: Yes, changing target value in xliff is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated.  Is this in documentation somewhere and I just missed it? or is there anywhere you can point me to find more details about how this works?

Comment: What do you want to read about? There are some links http://www.sylius.com/ http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF